# Mean of Shaded Region

Tags: probability

I Know $$E[x]=\frac1n\sum x \,\,p(x)$$

So given all points (including vertices and edges) in the triangle formed by vertices $(1,1),(1,0),(0,0)$, what is the mean of the $x$ values. Applying same formula, I get $$E[x]=\frac1{1-0}\int_0^1x^2\,dx=\frac13$$

But this just seems too low. If anything, mean would be greater than $\frac12$ because more value lie on right of half and there is no extreme value skewing mean in favour of $1/3$

Comment: It's a triangle.  You need a double integral.  And where does $x^2$ come from?  Don't you want $E(x)?$

Comment: ohhhh, thats what im doing wrong. i assumed pdf to be $x$ since its a straight line from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$

Comment: Right, integrate $x$ over the triangle, and divide by the area of the triangle.

Comment: @saulspatz, I'm not sure how to integrate over triangle. Can you help a bit more? Thank you!

Comment: Your first formula seems irrelevant; it is for a discrete distribution // For any of the rest this to make sense, you have to know the probability distribution of the points in the triangle. The simplest assumption might be that the points are uniformly distributed in the triangle. // Then if you're interested in the x-component of the points, you would proceed as in the (revised) Answer of @Adi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $E(X)$ is a *weighted average* of $X$ where the weights are determined by the particular probability distribution (characterized, in the continuous case, by the density $p(x)$). In the uniform case $p(x)=1$ and as expected $\int_0^1 x p(x)dx$ will be $1/2$. However, in your case, we have $p(x)=2x$ (you can use the CDF technique, finding $P(X \leq x)=x^2$ and differentiating). So now we're *averaging* the values $x$, with weights being $p(x)=2x$, which gives us
$$E(X)=\int_0^1 2x^2dx = 2/3$$

The negative skewness has drawn the probability mass to the right (clearly, larger values are getting more weights, as compared to the uniform case where all values get equal weights), in the process moving the expectation up, which was your intuition.

Comment: That is not what i'm looking for. Please see the comments on the post. My question wasn't why integral of x^2 is less than integral of x. I found 1/3 to be suprising because mean would be greater than half (And it is, 1/3 is not the correct mean)

Comment: @AFalseName Corrected. Please check.

Comment: If I'm correct, $$P(X\le x)=\frac{\text{Area of triangle 0 to x}}{\text{Total Area}}$$ Right?

Comment: $$P(X\le x)=\frac{\text{Area of triangle with base from 0 to x}}{\text{Area of triangle with base from 0 to 1}}$$
Here the numerator is $\frac{1}{2} \times x \times x$ and the denominator is $\frac{1}{2} \times 1 \times 1$ (using $\frac{1}{2} \times$ base $\times$ height formula).